# json string containing function calls

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

for example my json string is like this :

```
{
"v1" : [], 
"v2": 2, 
"v3": f()
}
```

Now the context in which I need to decode this has a definition of `f` and `f()` gives right answer in that context(checked via debugger). But `JSON.parse(jsonstring)` gives me `Unexpected token`. `eval` also gives error. What should I do?

See an example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/s2mve/)

Comment: This isn't a JSON string : " f()". Read http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why it does not work**

Look at the [definition](http://www.json.org/) of a JSON, it can not contain function calls.

**Possible workarounds**

One way is to do something like this, return a string of the function you want to call.

```
{
    "v1" : [], 
    "v2": 2, 
    "v3": "f"
}
```

Now when you need to access it, you can call the function.

```
var myJSON = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
var myFunctionResult = window[myJSON.v3]();  //works if global variable
```

Other option is to change how your code works and make an async script call [jQuery would be `getScript`, regular JavaScript `createElement("script")` with `appendChild()` and use a callback like JSONP does.

Comment: ok, but I think you understand what I want as result. Please respond accordingly.

Comment: Updated it with a possible solution[s].

Answer (score 0):

JSON strings cannot contain functions.

JSON is not the same things as a JavaScript object, even though the former is derived from the latter. Ultimately, it is a string.

Comment: ok, but I think you understand what I want as result. Please respond accordingly.

Comment: I really think it's in your interest to heed what all of us on this page are saying - that even attempting to shoehorn functions into your JSON (which, if you achieved it, would have to be evaluated from strings, because JSON cannot contain functions) is a bad idea. It suggests a flaw in the app design that needs to be addressed. A half-way house might be to mention function *names* in your JSON, but not the functions themselves.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use any callbacks or function calls in JSON (It is not valid JSON, it is insecure and it is absurd - two last things if you somehow make it work) , there is always way to do it in script.

EDIT: You REALLY don't need to call function from JSON - please return back to "drawing board" and design app to not use this pattern

Comment: ok, but I think you understand what I want as result. Please respond accordingly.

Comment: Yes, i see you have flaw in app design, "fixed" by function call in JSON

Comment: security is orthogonal to the issue, and there's plenty of valid use cases for it.